# Finding stock pairs whose spread is used for a risk neutral long-term investment

Tags: risk-management, cointegration, investing

I am currently working on researching about ways to improve returns in pairs trading. I had previously posted a reference request [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/68606/47318), where I had described a toy pair that seemed to be co-integrated.

While researching more about pairs trading, it got me thinking ... why not just buy the spread and hold it, if it has had a significant linear trend over the past whatever number of years? So here's what I did.

1. I found the spread using OLS, between pairs chosen from about seventy stocks from various sectors. Note that in order to avoid lookahead bias, only the first ninety days of data was chosen to find the OLS parameter.
   For pairs trading, we usually check if this spread is stationary. However, in this case, I tried to figure out if this spread is a "close to linear" trend. The following steps describe how I tried to do that.
2. I defined a ramp function and called it 'ramp', such that area under it is one, while it has the same length as the time series of the stock pairs chosen.

[image: Ramp Function]

3. The spread that I found between the stock pairs in #1, is then normalized so that it's area is again unity. It is plotted below.

[image: Normalized Spread]

4. I then form the spread, between the 'noramalized spread', obtained in #3, and the ramp function, shown in #2, in order to find the "energy content" in the error between these two time series. Unlike in #1, where only the first ninety days of data was used, I used the data from the entire series here because the idea is to find out how close the spread is, to the ramp.
   The standard deviation of the time series, obtained by taking the difference between the spread and the ramp, gives us the measure of this energy content. Ideally, I want it to be zero. The difference looks as shown in the following graph.

[image: Spread Between Spread and Ramp]

In this case, this energy content was $7.59e-5$ and it was the lowest amongst all the stock pairs in the list of seventy five stocks that I had.

So in conclusion, if I shorted, for every $6.46$ CSCO stocks that was bought, one USO stock (this parameter was obtained from OLS), then I get a spread that is reasonably close to a linear ramp. Just holding this over time should be profitable.

There were quite a few pairs from the list of seventy five stocks that I chose, which gave similar results. The nice thing about this approach is that it seems, from the outset, that it is risk neutral.

I would love to hear from you if I have made any error in any of my assumptions, in the steps I took to arrive at these results, and also, if you think that there could be factors which can potentially kill the profit.

Comment: "if you think that there could be factors which can potentially kill the profit." - maxDD of ~40% might do it (i.e. you could be forced to exit). I would also consider profit contribution from each leg. And in this case, you are long a tech stock in a bull market and short an oil ETF in an energy bear market, i.e. the PNL is highly regime-dependent.

Comment: @user42108 Thanks for the comments. I am yet to learn about how the broker deals with drawdowns. If I were holding this spread since 2015, then my account would suffer a drawdown of 25% mid 2019, and another 15% consequently. It makes sense that they force me out if I had just started, in 2019. But if I had started in 2015, then I don't know how things work. As regards to regimes, you are again right in that this has been the case for a much longer period. I actually tested from pre-crash times (2007 till present) and there are still many of these tech-Oil pairs which were profitable.

Comment: In fact, there were many other sector pairs which showed similar behavior. Take JNJ and BAC for instance. Pharma and banks form a great pair in that many of these pharma companies have ramped since 2007, while some of these banks are almost dead. So why not buy the winner with money borrowed from the looser? There is still that issue with the drawdown. In case of JNJ and BAC, the drawdown is still about 25% over the span of time from 2007 till now. As you rightly pointed, this needs to be managed. Perhaps having a portfolio of pairs, with different combination of sectors, might help.